# Desplegar multiples vistas en una vista

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-8

tengo una duda desde hace dias que no me deja descansar. Tengo una vista de un componente que se llama "ShowComponent" donde deberia mostrar dos vistas que son eventos y calendario:

**componente de ShowComponent**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Event;

use Livewire\Component;

class ShowComponent extends Component
{
    public $initialFilter = [
        "display_mode" => "table",
        "search" => ""
    ];
    public $filter;
    public $modal;

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->filter = $this->initialFilter;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.event.show-component');
    }

    public function changeDisplayMode($mode)
    {
        $this->filter['display_mode'] = $mode;
    }
}
```

**vista de ShowComponent**

```
<div class="flex flex-col md:flex-row">
    <div class="md:max-w-xs p-2 rounded shadow-lg">
        <div class="tabs tabs-lifted">
            @foreach (['table', 'calendar'] as $mode)
                <a class="capitalize tab {{ $mode == $filter['display_mode'] ? 'tab-active' : '' }}"
                    wire:click='changeDisplayMode("{{ $mode }}")'>{{ $mode }}</a>
            @endforeach
        </div>

        <x-input id="search" name="search" wire:model="filter.search" placeholder="Search event" />

        <a href="{{ route('events.new') }}" class="btn btn-neutral w-full mt-2">
            <x-icons.plus></x-icons.plus> New
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="mt-3 md:mt-0 md:ml-5">
        @if ($filter['display_mode'] == 'table')
            @include('livewire.Event.show-component.table-component')
        @elseif (['display_mode'] == 'calendar')
            @include('livewire.Event.show-component.calendar-component')
        @endif
    </div>
</div>
```

el problema sucede cuando entro a la vista show component solamente me carga la vista **livewire.Event.show-component.calendar-component** que es este:

```
<div class="overflow-x-auto">
    <table class="table table-zebra">
        <!-- head -->
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Customer</th>
                <th>Location</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Start time</th>
                <th>End time</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Notes</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <!-- row 1 -->
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Example Event</td>
                <td>John Doe</td>
                <td>Example Location</td>
                <td>2022-01-01</td>
                <td>10:00 AM</td>
                <td>12:00 PM</td>
                <td>$100</td>
                <td>Example Notes</td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

y no me carga la vista de calendario **'livewire.Event.show-component.calendar-component'** y este es la vista:

```
<div>
    <x-button wire:click='$set("modal", true)'>
        <x-dialog-modal wire:model="modal">
            <x-slot name="title"></x-slot>
            <x-slot name="content">
                <div id='calendar'></div>
            </x-slot>
            <x-slot name="footer"><x-button wire:click="$set('modal', false)"></x-button></x-slot>

        </x-dialog-modal>
    <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@6.1.9/index.global.min.js'></script>
    <script>
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        const calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        console.log(calendarEl)
        const calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
          initialView: 'dayGridMonth'
        });
        calendar.render();
      });
    </script>
</div>
```

porfavor alguna sugerencia que me pueda dar porfavor ya no tengo mas ideas para solucionar esto :C